# How to include the document id in Firestore collection in Angular 5

Tags: angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function that gets all the posts and I want to get the id of the post 
any idea how to get the id of the post or How to include the id when I add the document to the collection

```
get_the_posts(){
    this.Post_collection = this.afs.collection('posts'); 
    return this.Posts = this.Post_collection.valueChanges();
}
```

### That gives me this output:

```
[
   { name: 'post 1 name' description: 'post description'}, 
   { name: 'post 2 name' description: 'post description'},
   { name: 'post 3 name' description: 'post description'},
]
```

### And i want this output

```
[
   { id: 'm9mggfJtClLCvqeQ', name: 'post 1 name' description: 'post description'}, 
   { id: 'm9mggfJtCldsadaf', name: 'post 2 name' description: 'post description'},
   { id: 'm9mggfJtCdsasavq', name: 'post 3 name' description: 'post description'},
]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.valueChanges()` returns only data without any meta data. you can use `.snapshotChanges()` for that

```
this.Post_collection = this.afs.collection('posts');
return this.Posts = this.Post_collection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
  });
});
```

also import `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

For your second question how to add id when pushing data to firestore. try

```
//get id from firestore
    let id = this.afs.createId();

    this.post = {
      id:id,
      name:'name',
      description:'description'
    }

    this.afs.collection('posts').doc(id).set(this.post).then();
```

Now you can use `.valueChanges()` to get the data.

Comment: why not just do `.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });` ?

Comment: Oh.. just saw the date of your answer :D

Comment: This does not work for me. When i use the idfield option, and want to console.log(project.id) it, there is no value

Answer (score 26):

As of May, 10, 2019 you can now use:

```
valueChanges({idField?: string})
```

and pass in an optional field name that will contain the id of the document.

Such as in your original post:

```
get_the_posts(){
    this.Post_collection = this.afs.collection('posts'); 
    return this.Posts = this.Post_collection.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }); 
}
```

This would indeed return your objects in your desired output.

From the [Collections documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#streaming-collection-data):

> **Streaming collection data**
>
> There are multiple ways of streaming collection data from Firestore.
>
> **valueChanges({idField?: string})**
>
> What is it? - The current state of your collection. Returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array of JSON objects. All Snapshot metadata is stripped and just the document data is included. *Optionally, you can pass an options object with an idField key containing a string. If provided, the returned JSON objects will include their document ID mapped to a property with the name provided by idField.*

[Emphasis mine]

Comment: This does not work for me. When i use the idfield option, and want to console.log(project.id) it, there is no value

Answer (score 2):

I got so annoyed that there isn't a method for this, so I made one to share with everyone. Something this basic should be built into the the library itself.

```
getCollectionWithIDs(collection,key,comparison,value) {
    return this.afs.collection<any>(collection, ref => 
        ref.where(
            key, comparison, value
        )).snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(actions => actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
        })))
}
```

Note that this.afs is type AngularFirestore that should be in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this tip. Made my day.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the js spread operator and put that inside the query snapshot 
so using a bit of your code...

```
    async get_the_posts(){
        this.Post_collection = this.afs.collection('posts'); 
        return this.Posts = await this.Post_collection.onSnapshot(querySnapshot =>{
                        let arr = []
                        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                            arr.push({id:doc.id, ...doc.data()});

                        });
                        return arr
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, because I only want to get the data without subscribing to it, I'm adding the id in the then:

**If you want the data in a different object: **

```
await this.$fireStore
    .collection('SOME_COLLECTION')
    .doc('SOME_ID')
    .get()
    .then((item) => ({ id: item.id, data: item.data() }))
```

**If you want the data spread in the returned object: **

```
await this.$fireStore
    .collection('SOME_COLLECTION')
    .doc('SOME_ID')
    .get()
    .then((item) => ({ id: item.id, ...item.data() }))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use RXJS pipelines, easy read

```
AllDrivers() {
    return this.collection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(
        (action) => {
            return action.map( a => {
              return {...a.payload.doc.data(),
                id: a.payload.doc.id
              };
            });
        }
      ),
      take(1)
    );
```