# get the ID of collection document from Firestore using Angularfire2 in ionic 3

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to get id of the collection to use it in the ionic page:

this is my interface:

```
  export interface Item { 
  categoryOfPost: string; 
  imageUrl: string;
  nameOfPost: string;
  cityOfPost: string;
  createdDate: string;
  currencyOfPost: string;
  priceOfPost: number;
  typeOfPost: number;
  statusOfPost: string;
  id?: string;
}

 private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;
  items: Observable<Item[]>;
```

and this is the content of the getPosts function

```
  this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('posts', ref => ref.orderBy('createdDate', 'desc'));
  this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
```

when i want to view the content i use:

```
 <ion-card style="margin-bottom: 25px; background-color: burlywood" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <ion-item text-wrap  style="margin-bottom: 25px; background-color: burlywood"> 
        <ion-list >       
          <ion-item> 
            <img src="{{ item.imageUrl }}">            
            cityOfPost: {{ item.id }}            
          <button ion-button (click)="detailpage(item.id)">click to test  </button>
          </ion-item>           
        </ion-list>  
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
```

I can show everything on the HTML EXCEPT for the ID it comes UNDEFINED ????
what is the correct way to display it ???

Thank you.

Comment: Created a function for this basic problem. It's at the [bottom of this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254978/how-to-include-the-document-id-in-firestore-collection-in-angular-5). Not sure why this just isn't part of AngularFire2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because by using `valueChanges()` "all Snapshot metadata is stripped and just the method provides only the data", as explained in the [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#valuechanges).

You should use `snapshotChanges()`, see the doc [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges) which says: "Why would you use it? - When you need a list of data but also want to keep around metadata."

Answer (score 1):

i changed the code to:

```
  this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('posts', ref => ref.orderBy('createdDate', 'desc'));
  this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Item;
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return { id, ...data };
    }))
  );
```

and it worked perfectly.